# menu width differ with sub-menu in long dropdowns

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I'm tring to use [this solution](http://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/) for scrollable Long Drop-down, but the sub-menu(content) width must same as menu.

Is there any way to make it in different width?

```
menu { width : 30px; }
submenu { width : 300px; }
```

Comment: I tried to add a width setting in ul.dropdown ul li , but no success. I had also tried add the width into $list.css and $container.css, still no respond...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/moscorp/gTLvJ/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to adjust the width of:

```
ul.dropdown li //main menu
ul.dropdown ul //submenu
```

Comment: I tried to  add a width setting in ul.dropdown ul li , but no success. I had also tried add the width into $list.css and $container.css, still no respond...

Comment: You also have to increase the #page-wrap width too!

Comment: Hello Charles, thanks for comment. But, what I want to do is to make different width in between main menu and sub menu. Such as mainmenu { width : 30px; } submenu { width : 300px; } , rather than the same room's width.

Comment: Anyone found solution? Am hunting and trying to make the scrollable menu width of different size than top first level menu. :(